# Android: Set Widgets Once Only using FindViewById

Tags: android, widget

Right now, every time I want to access a widget I use:

```
    mEditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
```

And then perform the action I would like to on the widget.

However, I am wondering if I am able to store a reference to a widget and use that reference multiple times in different methods within the activity, without having to always call findViewById...

I've tried the following:

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity {

        public static String ACTIVITY_NAME = "MyActivity";
        EditText mEditText1;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Log.v(this.APP_NAME, "In " + ACTIVITY_NAME);

            mEditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);

            setContentView(R.layout.main); 
            prefillFieldsIfNecessary();

       }

       private void prefillFieldsIfNecessary(){
          if(AppPreferences.checkExistence(MyActivity.this, AppPreferences.Name)) {
              mEditText1.setText(AppPreference.Name);
       }
```

However, my app just crashes and I get a NullPointerException, which I know speaks to the mEditText1.setText() line, because when I comment that out, my app runs fine.

Answer (score 2):

Asha, this should work and is completely valid. How do you know it's not working? Are you getting an error? Is textToSave not being populated appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you're declaring "EditText mEditText1;" *after* your import statements and *before* your class declaration. Also specify an access modifier, not specifying an access modifier to a class field is not good. It would be nice if you can post a full example of your Activity, so that we can see if you're declaring "EditText mEditText1;" as a class member or variable.

**Edit:** 
Move

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

right after

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

and you'll be fine. Generally try to have those 2 lines
on top of your onCreate() and do all logic, after those 2 lines.

Comment: thanks have update to include more detail here.
Since this is an instance variable, i'm assuming the proper access modifier is "private";

Comment: Well, back to your initial question about the references. Your code is correct in that term. The problem is in the order of your method calls.